# Or-Operator in return statement

Tags: c#

I stumbled upon this piece of code, which I truly do not understand so far.
I clearly know what the or-operator `||` does in codes like these:

```
bool a = true;
bool b = false;
if(a || b)
{
   //does something, if one of a/b is true
}
```

But this is a structure, I do not understand:

```
public bool c
{
   get
   {
      return a || b; //?
   }
   set
   {
      c = value;
   }
}
```

What will this getter return with that return-statement and why?

Comment: It means the same. `return true if a or b is true else return false`

Comment: I hope this is sample code: witha property name of `c`, the set-statement of `c=value` will result in a StackOverflowException.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will return the resulting value of:

```
a || b
```

Which would be a boolean.  (Notice that the function signature indicates that it returns a `bool`.)  This is essentially no different from your other example:

```
if(a || b)
```

An `if` statement expects something that evaluates to a boolean, which an `||` on two values does.

You can usually think of the `return` keyword as having the same [operator precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) as an assignment statement (it's "assigning" a value to the return path of the function on the stack).  So you can imagine an implied set of parentheses here:

```
return (a || b);
```

First evaluate `a || b`, then call `return` on the value.

Answer (score 0):

It will return true if either a OR b are true

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, it will return true of either a or b is true (or both are true).

Answer (score 0):

It's equal to:

```
public bool c
{
   get
   {
      if(a || b)
         return true;
      else
         return false;
   }
   set
   {
      c = value;
   }
}
```